# SQL Server PWDEncrypt vs Salted Password Hashing

Tags: sql-server, security, hash

What is more secure? Using the SQL Server PWDENCRYPT(@Whatever) function, or a [Properly implemented secure hash](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)?

We are conflicted, on one side we have the secure hashing process seen [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode), it generates iterations:salt:hash, and to compare both we need to pass the Password String inputed by the user (For example, in a web-form), but to compare the password we need to get from the database the hashed string in the format iterations:salt:hash.

Problem is, if we use PWDEncrypt we can't really obtain the value back from the server which is needed to successfully compare the inputted hash vs server stored hash. This means we cannot use both approaches, we need to pick either the PWDEncrypt DB, or the iterations:salt:hash method.

On the other hand we have PWDEncrypt, as far as I know it also hashes the password, and then we can use PWDCompare to determine if everything is the same.

From a security standpoint, which approach should we take? Should we use the Database native PWDEncrypt? Or should we go for the other implementation.

Does it even matter? And what would be the cascade effect on our application security for either approach?

Comment: From [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791.aspx): "PWDENCRYPT is an older function and might not be supported in a future release of SQL Server."

Comment: Yeah, read that a bit ago. Considering Encrypt by Key or Encrypt by Cert.